# how skip row if other rows exists

Tags: mysql, t-sql

I'm trying to come up with a simple SQL statement that will help be output what the user needs:

```
  SELECT 
    tbl, bundleID, productID, quantity, cardValue, a.title, orderLineGUID
  FROM
  (
    SELECT 'OLNOVPS' tbl, ol.orderLineGUID, ol.bundleID, 
           ol.productID, ol.quantity, ol.cardValue, m.title 
      from orderLinesNoVPS ol 
      inner JOIN productMeta m ON ol.productID = m.productID
      where ol.orderID = 31687478 

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 'OL' tbl, ol.orderLineGUID, ol.bundleID, 
            ol.productID, ol.quantity, ol.cardValue, m.title 
      from orderLines ol 
      inner JOIN productMeta m ON ol.productID = m.productID
      where ol.orderID = 31687478 
  ) a
  WHERE 
    a.productID > 100000;
```

and the result is:

[image]

**What I want to accomplish** is only showing the first 2 rows, as `OLNOVPS` takes precedent in the `OL`...

*in other words*, if `OLNOVPS` + `orderLineGUID` exist, then `OL` should not be shown, if it does not exist, it should be show the `OL` as there's no `OLNOVPS` precedent

can anyone give me a hand... I'm a bit stuck on this part.

Comment: @TimSchmelter try to see how much money you spend in licenses to use MS SQL in a production environment ;)

Comment: @balexandra: that was not a rhetoric question since the IDE is  SSMS, isn't it?

Comment: For mySQL, I use [dbForge Studio for MySQL](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/) (paid license) cause I was done with the free MySQL Workbench and I added `mysql` cause for example, I can't use  the `WITH` clause (would help a lot here)

Comment: @Blam you can't use MSSQL Express in production environment, see the license agreement, and it's a terrible database (only 1CPU and max of 1Gb of RAM and 10Gb of size... we're already in the 30Gb+ in size, and using 24Gb of ram on the server) - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993.aspx

Comment: @Blam, with 2012 version I can see now you can, but the limitations on CPU and RAM, you should never use it, unless you have a really small and low in traffic site. This is an e-commerce site (as you can see by `orderID` clauses) and we do get a lot of users per day, plus, you need to multiply for 5 countries as we're using the same webiste (IIS) and same DB (mySQL) for all. works pretty speedy but can't have the queries I could use in MS SQL... mySQL is not 100% T-SQL complaint.

Comment: Understand Express does not meet your needs. But I would not classify 10 GB as really small.  It was just a question.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit ugly but it would work...

You could use the

```
IF (exists(SELECT 'OLNOVPS' tbl, ol.orderLineGUID, ol.bundleID, 
       ol.productID, ol.quantity, ol.cardValue, m.title 
  from orderLinesNoVPS ol 
  inner JOIN productMeta m ON ol.productID = m.productID
  where ol.orderID = 31687478 ))
BEGIN
  SELECT 'OLNOVPS' tbl, ol.orderLineGUID, ol.bundleID, 
       ol.productID, ol.quantity, ol.cardValue, m.title 
  from orderLinesNoVPS ol 
  inner JOIN productMeta m ON ol.productID = m.productID
  where ol.orderID = 31687478 
END
ELSE
    SELECT 'OL' tbl, ol.orderLineGUID, ol.bundleID, 
        ol.productID, ol.quantity, ol.cardValue, m.title 
  from orderLines ol 
  inner JOIN productMeta m ON ol.productID = m.productID
  where ol.orderID = 31687478 
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this possibly work? (ugly)

```
  SELECT 
    case when min(tbl) = 1 then 'OLNOVPS' else 'OL' end as tbl, bundleID, productID, quantity, cardValue, a.title, orderLineGUID
  FROM
  (
    SELECT 1 tbl, ol.orderLineGUID, ol.bundleID, 
           ol.productID, ol.quantity, ol.cardValue, m.title 
      from orderLinesNoVPS ol 
      inner JOIN productMeta m ON ol.productID = m.productID
      where ol.orderID = 31687478 

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 2 tbl, ol.orderLineGUID, ol.bundleID, 
            ol.productID, ol.quantity, ol.cardValue, m.title 
      from orderLines ol 
      inner JOIN productMeta m ON ol.productID = m.productID
      where ol.orderID = 31687478 
  ) a
  WHERE 
    a.productID > 100000
  GROUP BY
    bundleID, productID, quantity, cardValue, a.title, orderLineGUID
```